# XPath: Question concerning the p-Element from HTML

Tags: xpath

I have a question concerning XPath and the p-element from HTML. Let's say I'm confronted with an HTML-structure that looks like this:

```
<div id="this-is-a-text">
This is text segment 1.
<p>This is text segment 2.</p>
this is text segment 3.
<div id="this-is-not-part-of-the-text">This doesn't belong to the text.</div>
This is text segment 4.
</div>
```

I'm wondering what's the correct way to parse all all text segments no matter if they're inside a p-element or not? (NB: The the sequence of the elements is random.)

What I don't understand is why **//div[@id="this-is-a-text"]/p** seems to do the job (instead of just returning text segment 3), whereas **//div[@id="this-is-a-text"]/text()** doesn't return any results at all.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Thanks!

Bob

Comment: Well your first path expression `//div[@id="this-is-a-text"]/p` selects all `p` child elements of the `div` element with `id` attribute value `this-is-a-text`. In your input sample there is a single such `p` child elements with the text "This is text segment 2.". I don't understand why you say it does the job, nor do I understand why you say it should return "segment 3". And `//div[@id="this-is-a-text"]/text()` should return all text child nodes of the div, there three of that kind ("segment 1", "segment 3", "segment 4"). So how do you test those paths that you get odd results?

Comment: Hello Martin, I'm looking for a way to select both text inside p-elements and text that isn't inside p-elements for some reason. I don't want any other text, though (like text inside div-elements, headlines and so on). In fact, `//div[@id="this-is-a-text"]/text()` doesn't return any results. That's what I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin Honnen mentioned, query `//div[@id="this-is-a-text"]/text()` should return set of three text segments:

```
"\nThis is text segment 1.\n",
"\nthis is text segment 3.\n",
"\nThis is text segment 4.\n"
```

If I understand your question right, you need query like

```
//div[@id="this-is-a-text"]//text()
```

And this should return set:

```
"\nThis is text segment 1.\n",
"This is text segment 2.",
"\nthis is text segment 3.\n",
"This doesn't belong to the text.",
"\nThis is text segment 4.\n"
```